# SQL Server Script Block number and block line

Tags: sql-server

The error message when running my scripts includes:

Script block number: 9512; Block line 25;

What is a Script block number and how do I go to it in Visual Studio? (I'm using dbUp to create my database.

Comment: Sounds like something specific to dbUp...probably the deploy script it built. Wondering why you're not using Visual studio database tools to deploy - it's pretty smart about reading the existing db and making a deployment script that can modify the db in-place.

Comment: I am forced to use dbUp by the db admin.

Comment: Yeah - I know how that kind of thing goes. See if you can find the script file it built - bet it has some comments that number blocks and lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about Clay's comments, I went out to the source code for dbUp, which is over at the Git website. It turns out that the block line is the same as the sqlException.LineNumber. SqlException.LineNumber Property, according to MSDN, "Gets the line number within the Transact-SQL command batch or stored procedure that generated the error." So, now I have my answer!

Comment: GitHub website, just to be clear. DbUp can be found at https://dbup.github.io/ . How about the Block Number, what  does that reference? Found my own answer, it is the script number it is actually running, in the case that you have more than one script in a file. The index is zero based.